# java vst host library

Tags: java, vst

I'm writing a simple sequencer in java and I'd like to host vst instruments as well.
What would be the best library I can use to add vst functionality?

I've found [jvsthost](https://github.com/mhroth/jvsthost) but I want to be shure that there is not a better choice before I start using it. Particularly the following line about jvsthost scares me a lot:

> NOTE: Not all synths work. If you have one that you are particularly keen on working with, please e-mail us and we'll try to debug it with you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, jvsthost is the only Java way to host VST's, short of diving into JNI and doing it yourself. So I'd say it's probably worth a try until you run into the aforementioned problems, in which case it's open source and you can always patch it. ;)

Comment: Quick evaluation by another guy who tried to get it working - couldn't get sound out on the Windows version. Mac version didn't have a binary for Intel processors and the code was too old to compile for any modern OSX SDK. It's true that patching it would be possible, but to a guy who has never done OSX event programming, it looks like almost as much work as rewriting it.

Comment: Yeah, the mac version definately doesnt work , and seems to have a positively ancient processor requirement, possibly even PowerPC (Definately not modern 64 bit macs). Java, write once , run anywhere!

Answer (score 0):

There is [JVST](http://jvst.sourceforge.net/), though I did not try it yet.

Comment: C++ code seems very Windows-specific. :(